# Chef::Exceptions::InvalidRemoteFileURI , How to download a jar file using a recipe

Tags: chef-infra

```
web_app_jar = Chef::Config[:file_cache_path] + 'http://1.1-SNAPSHOT/20170803.130333-19.jar
'

spring_boot_web_app 'app_0' do
    jar_remote_path web_app_jar
end

spring_boot_web_app 'app_1' do
    jar_remote_path web_app_jar
    user 'another_bootapp_user'
    group 'another_bootapp_group'
    port 8091

    wait_for_http true
    wait_for_http_retries 30
    wait_for_http_retry_delay 2
end

spring_boot_web_app 'app_0' do
    action :uninstall
end

spring_boot_web_app 'no-such-app' do
    action :uninstall
end
```

error

```
    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `install` on resource 'spring_boot_web_app[app_0]'
    ================================================================================

    Chef::Exceptions::InvalidRemoteFileURI
    --------------------------------------
    "/var/chef/cachehttp://http://1.1-SNAPSHOT/20170803.130333-19.jar\n" is not a valid `source` parameter for remote_file. `source` must be an absolute URI or an array of URIs.

    Cookbook Trace:
    ---------------
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/spring-boot/providers/web_app.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in class_from_file'
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/spring-boot/providers/web_app.rb:27:in `block in class_from_file'

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/spring-boot/recipes/example.rb

      4: spring_boot_web_app 'app_0' do
      5:    jar_remote_path web_app_jar
      6: end
      7: 

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/spring-boot/recipes/example.rb:4:in `from_file'

    spring_boot_web_app("app_0") do
      action [:install]
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      declared_type :spring_boot_web_app
      cookbook_name "spring-boot"
      recipe_name "example"
      jar_remote_path "/var/chef/cachehttp://http://1.1-SNAPSHOT/20170803.130333-19.jar\n"
      user "bootapp"
      group "bootapp"
    end

    System Info:
    ------------
    chef_version=12.21.3
    platform=redhat
    platform_version=7.2
    ruby=ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
    program_name=chef-client worker: ppid=20573;start=09:16:14;
    executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client
```

Comment: What's unclear in the error message ? `"/var/chef/cachehttp://http://1.1-SNAPSHOT/20170803.130333-19.jar\n" is not a valid `source` parameter for remote_file. `source` must be an absolute URI or an array of URIs.` Obvisouly `/var/whatever` is not the start of an uri...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a URI as a Unix file path, notably `//` is not allowed in Unix paths. The usual workaround is something like this: `web_app_jar = "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/#{uri.split(%r{/}).last}"`, i.e. use just the last file component.